# Why is the filter needed for low resolution GMOS spectroscopy?

Tags: spectroscopy, filter, grating, gmos

I am considering writing a proposal for using the GMOS with the R150 grating. I want to measure the redshift of multiple systems from the strong lensing effect of some clusters, so the redshift range is wide (1<z<5). Therefore, it is better if the wavelength coverage is broad. However, when I use any filter as shown in the figure below, the wavelength range becomes narrower. Additionally, there is a loss in Signal-to-Noise (S/N) ratio if I use any filter.

For example, when I use the 'GG455 G0329' filter, there is a loss of the blue wavelength range and S/N compared to when I use no filter.

For me, it seems the best option is not to use any filter. Am I right?

[image: Filter system for GMOS-S]

P.S. I also add the grating efficiency of R150 below.

[image]

Comment: Are there any filters that have a wide enough bandwidth so that the radiation is not attenuated at the required frequencies? Is it possible to design a filter with a given bandwidth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic grating equation is
$$\sin \theta_d = \frac{n \lambda}{d} - \sin \theta_i\ , $$
where $\lambda$ is the wavelength of light, $d$ is the groove spacing on the grating, $\theta_i$ is the angle to the grating normal of the incident light (this is fixed and independent of wavelength) and $\theta_d$ is the angle to the normal of the diffracted light. $n$ is the "order" of the diffration and is an integer - $n=1, 2...$

Your spectrum is formed by diffracting light of different wavelengths at different $\theta_d$ and recording the signal on a CCD. If you are using a diffraction grating say at red wavelengths with $n=1$, then it is possible to get blue light diffracted at the same angle if $n=2$. This would make your spectrum uninterpretable, since your detected spectrum would be an inseparable mixture of blue and red light (astronomical CCDs are monochrome of course). Normally, you would use a broad "order sorting" filter so that you do not get unintended pollution of your light from a different diffraction order.

For example, if you intended to collect a spectrum at 700-900 nm in order 1, then you don't want it polluted by light at 350-450 nm in order 2. By inserting the GG455 G0329 you make sure that light with $\lambda < 450$ nm cannot reach the detector.

Spectrographs with really broad wavelength coverage would usually have some arrangement to ensure that light of different wavelengths cannot fall on the same pixels on the detector - having multiple arms and detectors, with a dichroic to split the light (e.g., [ISIS on the WHT](https://www.ing.iac.es/astronomy/instruments/isis/)) or a cross-disperser to separate the orders perpendicular to the dispersion (mostly high resolution, echelle spectrographs), or even both (like [Xshooter at the VLT](https://www.eso.org/sci/facilities/paranal/instruments/xshooter/overview.html)). GMOS does not have these capabilities and a blocking filter must be used when doing spectroscopy at $\lambda > 660$ nm unless for some reason you know your objects are invisible at wavelengths of $\lambda/2$.

EDIT: You didn't say whether you were using GMOS in long-slit or multi-object slit-mask mode. If the latter, then an additional reason for using a filter is to shorten the recorded spectrum so there is less chance of an overlap with the spectrum of another object in the same slit mask, especially if the field might be observed at various rotation angles.